# How can I hoist an object definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hoisting

In my `js` file in an Angular app I am building, I want to declare the `controller`s, `service`s etc up top, and then define them below.

I have this working for now and it's fine. The problem is, when I start a new file, I typically copy over the contents of an existing file and change the names of the functions. However, I have to go through a whole bunch of function names which is a pain. I'd rather simply change the name of the object containing these functions, and then only change

```
oldapp.controller
```

to

```
newapp.controller
```

For better illustration, **this is what I have now**

```
var pos__filejs_HomeApp = angular.module('ros.filejs.HomeApp', ['ui.router']);

pos_filejs_config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
pos__filejs_HomeApp.config(pos_filejs_config);

pos_filejs_controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
pos__filejs_HomeApp.controller('ros.postjs.ctrl', pos_filejs_controller);

//----------------------------------------------------
//  FUNCTIONS
//----------------------------------------------------

function pos_filejs_config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  // implementation
}

function pos_filejs_controller($scope){
  //implementation
}
```

and here's **what I want to have:**

```
var pos__filejs_HomeApp = angular.module('ros.filejs.HomeApp', ['ui.router']);

HomeApp.config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
pos__filejs_HomeApp.config(HomeApp.config);

HomeApp.controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
pos__filejs_HomeApp.controller('ros.postjs.ctrl', HomeApp.controller);

//----------------------------------------------------
//  FUNCTIONS
//----------------------------------------------------

var HomeApp = {
  config: function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    // implementation
  },
  controller: function ($scope){
    //implementation
  }
}
```

This is quite a bit cleaner, especially as the files get bigger and more services, configs, are added.

The problem is, I can't seem to put the object implementation below the angular stuff because the object is not "hoisted" - that is, the reference to `HomeApp` at the top of the file is `undefined` since `HomeApp` is only defined lower down (it is not like this for `function name(){...}`.

How can I hoist the object so I can use it higher up in the file?

Comment: Forget the term "hoisting", it's misleading. What actually happens is that variable declarations are processed before any code is executed (which initialises the variables to *undefined*). Then code execution begins, top down. So you can only assign a value "higher up" if you move the assignment "higher up".

Comment: But if it works for variables, is there a way to get it to work for objects?

Comment: "*So you can only assign a value higher up if you move the assignment higher up*".

Comment: That's not true, you can assign `var abc = "abc"` at the end of your code and the code at the top will know what it is

Comment: @Imray, in your example, the `abc` variable will be hoisted at the top of the code.  But it will be undefined.  See http://jsfiddle.net/ythaspzp/

Comment: @Imray—not in any implementation consistent with ECMA-262. If you think about it, it's logically impossible to "hoist" assignments in a general case. Your confusion is my primary argument against the use of the term "hoisting", it infers that the entire statement is moved to the top of the execution context, when nothing of the sort happens.

Comment: But it does happen with `function(){...}`, how does that work?

Comment: @Imray—per ECMA-262. When entering an execution context, all variable declarations are processed (e.g. in `var name = 'foo'`,  just the `var name` part is processed) to create local variables that are initially assigned the *undefined* value. After that, function declarations are processed to create more local variables and the function bodies are assigned to the names. After that, code execution begins, top down. During execution, variables may be assigned values (e.g. the `name = 'foo'` part from above). Variable declarations with an initialiser are processed in two parts, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HomeApp is hoisted however HomeApp hoisted as "undefined". Hoisting does not defines value for you. According to me, You can think of code as

```
    var HomeApp = undefined;   
var pos__filejs_HomeApp = angular.module('ros.filejs.HomeApp', ['ui.router']);

    HomeApp.config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
//Here HomeApp is undefined, Since you haven't assign any value;

    pos__filejs_HomeApp.config(HomeApp.config);
    HomeApp.controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
    pos__filejs_HomeApp.controller('ros.postjs.ctrl', HomeApp.controller);
//...
```

> I am not sure why you wanna to write a code which is hard to
>   understand :-D